# Preciso retornar os valores null deste inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho este `select` do MySQL:

```
SELECT credor.nome, banco.descricao FROM credor
INNER JOIN banco ON (credor.banco = banco.codigo)
```

Ele me retorna todos os credores e seu respectivo banco, mas se o banco do cara é NULL ele simplesmente não me retorna o registro.

Como posso fazer para retornar o registro, mas na descrição ficar NULL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O que o `INNER JOIN` faz é justamente eliminar os `NULL`s. Ele só estabelece relacionamento quando não houver `NULL` em nenhuma das pontas.

O que você está querendo é feito com `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT credor.nome, banco.descricao FROM credor
LEFT JOIN banco ON (credor.banco = banco.codigo)
```

Aqui no site tem uma excelente explicação sobre os tipos de `JOIN`: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer da seguinte forma abaixo que ira retornar os valores `NULL`:

```
SELECT credor.nome, banco.descricao FROM credor
  INNER JOIN banco ON (
    if(credor.banco is null, 0, credor.banco) = if(banco.codigo is null, 0, banco.codigo)
  )
```